# How can i store a textboxt text for an array and restore it later?

Tags: c#, winforms, tabs

What i want to do is: I have a "+" button, that creates a new tab every click, and one textbox. I want to do every tab create a text array for the same textbox (1 textbox, having different values according to the selected tabcontrol tab.) i have a maximum value of 5 tabs that i set, how can i do that?

i searched alot on how to create it, but didnt found a specific one for what i need

code of tabcontrols

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(tabControl1.TabPages.Count != 5)
    {
        page++;
        string title = "Script " + page.ToString();
        TabPage tabipage = new TabPage(title);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabipage);
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You cant add more tabs!");
    }
}
```

also, doesnt need to be exactly an array, just need to save and restore values between tabs

Comment: Between tabs, or between running the program, stopping it and running it again?

Comment: between tabs only

Comment: @VUDUEPRAJACU `I want to do every tab create a text array for the same textbox` => You mean these tabs have these specific arrays, then loading selected tab value into textbox ?

Comment: Please rename your controls after you add them to your form. It takes seconds to do and means that you (and other people you ask for help) will be able to understand your program as it grows more complex. Good names are vital; just think if Microsoft didn't name things well, and instead just called *everything* by the pattern *thing+number* your code might look like `if(tabPage1.Array1.Integer1 != 5) tabPage1.Array1.Method2(tabPage2)` - meaningless garbage!

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty open ended question, and you'll have to forgive me if I misunderstood. What I'm guessing is you have a tab control, and OUTSIDE the tab control you have a single textbox that should change based on which tab is selected? If so you could do something similar to the below:

```
    class tabWithScript : TabPage
    {
        public tabWithScript(string title) : base(title)
        { }

        public string myscript { get; set; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count < 5)
        {
            string title = "Script " + (tabControl1.TabPages.Count +1 ).ToString();
            tabWithScript tabipage = new tabWithScript(title);

            tabipage.myscript = $"Oh man, this is my script {tabControl1.TabPages.Count +1}";
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabipage);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You cant add more tabs!");
        }
    }

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            tabWithScript myTab = (tabWithScript)tabControl1.SelectedTab;

            textBox1.Text = myTab.myscript;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
}
```

Instead of using the default TabPage object you can create your own class that inherits TabPage, then store whatever information you want in there. (You'd likely have to delete the default TabPages the tabcontrol creates).

Alternatively, you can just create a string array and index it appropriately e.g.

```
    string[] myList = new string[5];
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count < 5)
        {
            string title = "Script " + (tabControl1.TabPages.Count +1 ).ToString();
            TabPage tabipage = new TabPage(title);

            myList[tabControl1.TabPages.Count] = $"Oh man, this is my script {tabControl1.TabPages.Count +1}";
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabipage);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You cant add more tabs!");
        }
    }

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = myList[tabControl1.SelectedIndex];
    }
```

`

Answer (score 1):

An alternative of @Devon Page's solution is using the `Tag` property, existing in almost all controls, to store value.

```
    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (tabControl1.TabPages.Count < 5)
        {
            page++;
            string title = "Script " + page.ToString();
            TabPage tabipage = new TabPage(title);
            tabipage.Tag = title; //Store whatever you want.
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tabipage);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You cant add more tabs!");
        }
    }

    private void tabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = tabControl1.SelectedTab.Tag.ToString(); // Cast to restore it
    }
```

Comment: I approve - this solution is simple, easy and what .Tag was intended for